# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR extracts strings by blank when there are multiple blanks

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

Hi I'm new to Oracle SQL, I want to extract `LiIon Polymer` from `6Cell LiIon Polymer`.

I use `REGEXP_SUBSTR('6Cell LiIon Polymer', '\S+', 7)` but it only returns `LiIon`

Comment: What do you really want?  Anything after the first word? The last 2 words?  Anything after the first word with a number in it? Anything after the first space?  What if the first word's description was "6 cell" with a space in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want substring that follows the first space? Use *good, old* `substr` + `instr` combination. Sample data first, query you might be interested in begins at line #4.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '6Cell LiIon Polymer' from dual)
  3  --
  4  select substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
-------------
LiIon Polymer

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular expression and without hardcoding

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('6Cell LiIon Polymer', '[^\S]+', instr('6Cell LiIon Polymer', ' '), 1) from dual;
```

Comment: The first space is being selected.  I believe you want `REGEXP_SUBSTR('6Cell LiIon Polymer', '.*? (.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Oh yes, i missed it, It should be select REGEXP_SUBSTR('6Cell LiIon Polymer', '[^\S]+', instr('6Cell LiIon Polymer', ' ') + 1, 1) from dual;